# How can I randomize for example the scale of two different cubes with one 'Random Value' node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I tried to look for answers here but I'm still lost

So how to have different scale values from the 'Random Value' node for the scale of the cubes?

[image]

Comment: Do you need to only use one node, or only _control it_ from one node? For example, you could connect the output of the random value node to either the max or min input of a second random value node used only in the "node chain" for your second cube, and both could still be controlled by manipulating the seed value of the first random value node.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I don't understand - I feel that no matter how complex randomize scenario is built, all the inputs still take only one same 'randomized' number and by so display the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This came in Twitter, seems to solve at least this specific issue:

From **Jason Clarke @JtheNinja**:

> Scale should go after the join, so when it evaluates the random value
> (specifically the "seed" field) it should do it across all the
> objects. Right now you're doing it discretely per object, it never
> knows about the combined system

[image]